# Dlib library is not installing on Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, dlib

I need to install `dlib` library on my Anaconda and this page in the image doesn't show any thing. Even when I use

```
pip install dlib
```

It doesn't install.

[image: install results]

Answer (score 0):

you can install via conda channels by using following command on anaconda prompt,

**conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.17**

version is depends upon you @obadeji